# What are the drawbacks of using empty image instead of ajax for post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes when I only need to send data and I don't care to send it via GET I just use this:

```
var t = new Image();
t.src = 'get.php?arg1='+arg1+'&arg2='+arg2....;
```

I would like to know what drawback does it have to use such a method ? Or is it perfectly fine to use this method for posting data via GET method and emulating AJAX?

Answer (score 4):

Id' rather use AJAX for sending AJAX requests. Browsers evolve, XHR object as well so there might be some optimizations that you won't be able to benefit from if you are using images.

Comment: +1 But much quicker to use an empty image instead of adding full blown cross browser ajax library :) Could you tell me more about optimisations?

Comment: such optimizations are probably minute compared to the overhead of loading a javascript framework/ajax library

Answer (score 1):

The practical drawback is probably the lack of an error handler but should be perfectly fine if you don't care if your request truly succeeds.

Note: Browsers are optimized to request images too... :)

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, I use it only when I don't care about the data success and actually just want to send it and forget as soon as I did that. However I am thinking what failures can it bring if used somewhere outside the playfield

Comment: You'll actually have an `onerror` that you can listen to, in the case of the image coming back with any status 400+.